# Multiple dynamic filter with nested level array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

Input :

```js
// First Array
const input1 = [{
    'name': "name1",
    'email': "email1@email.com",
    'age': 10,
    'score':95,
    'address': {
      'city': "city1"
    }
  },
  {
    'name': "name2",
    'email': "email2@email.com",
    'age': 10,
    'score':45,
    'address': {
      'city': "city2"
    }
  }
];

// Second Array
const input2 = [{
    'id': 1,
    'fullname': "name1",
    'emailaddress': "email1@email.com",
    'age': 10,
    'score':45,
    'address': {
      'city': "city1"
    }
  },
  {
    'id': 5,
    'name': "name2",
    'email': "email2@email.com",
    'age': 20,
    'score':55,
    'address': {
      'city': "city2"
    }
  }
];
 
 const filter1 = [{
  "filter1Key": "age",
  "filter2Key": "score"
}];
const filter2 = [{
  "filter1Key": "name",
  "filter2Key": "address.city"
}];

const newArray = [];
cont updateArray = [];

//Below code is not is giving 

const test1 = input1.filter((data) => input2.some((obj) =>
     filter1.every(key => data[key.filter1Key] === obj[key.filter2Key])?filter2.every(key => data[key.filter1Key] === obj[key.filter2Key])?'':updateArray.push(obj):newArray.push(obj)));
console.log(test1);
```

First all the unmatched record with filter1 of input1 should be push into newArray and unmatched record with filter2 of input1 should be push into updateArray but id of  inout2 should also push with that record

```
Expected output:
newArray = [{
        'name': "name1",
        'email': "email1@email.com",
        'age': 10,
        'score':95,
        'address': {
          'city': "city1"
        }
      }];

updateArray =  [{
        'id': 5,
        'name': "name2",
        'email': "email2@email.com",
        'age': 10,
        'score':45,
        'address': {
          'city': "city2"
        }
      }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the first ? to && and the second ? to == and the first : to ?

Comment: Not working. Also Nested level match should also work

Answer (score 0):

you may change below code by your es6+ syntax--
I wish It might help you

```js
input1.forEach((input1Item) => {
    const x = input2.find((input2Item) =>{
        return input1Item[filter1[0].filter1Key] === input2Item[filter1[0].filter1Key] && input1Item[filter1[0].filter2Key] === input2Item[filter1[0].filter2Key]
    })    
    const y = input2.find((input2Item) =>{
        return input1Item[filter1[0].filter1Key] !== input2Item[filter1[0].filter1Key] || input1Item[filter1[0].filter2Key] !== input2Item[filter1[0].filter2Key]
    })
    if(!x){        
        newArray.push(input1Item)
    } else if(y){
        updateArray.push({ id: y.id , ...input1Item})
    }    
});
```

Comment: input1 and input2 array can have 500 object but your solution is not working for these case